# my error is this "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'FastColoredTextBoxNS.FastColoredTextBox' to 'string'" and the code is CS1503

Tags: c#

{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
EasyExploits.Module module = new Module();

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void flatButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => Module.ExecuteScript(fastColoredTextBox1);
```

Comment: please, edit your question according to the guides. Also, could it be fastColoredTextBox1.Text?

Comment: umm yeah and can you help me with some more errors and i fixed it. its was that the module "m" was in caps and the fastcoloredtextbox.text

Comment: you can add me on discord BIGCHUNGUS#4898